# How can the Wigner function of squeezed states be non-negative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

It is always said that when the Wigner function of quantum states takes a negative value, then it is a clear signature of non-classicality of this particular state. It is also well-known that the Wigner function of squeezed states is completely non-negative, yet, we still call squeezed states quantum. How does one explain this supposed contradiction here? is the Wigner function just not a "strong enough" measure of non-classicality? if so, what is? Also, what defines non-classicality for that matter (specifically for squeezed states)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think squeezed states are supposed to be necessarily quantum, right? In the simplest 2 particles in 1d oscillator framework, don't they classically describe the two particles being a quarter period out of phase with each other?

Comment: @user1379857 squeezed states are non-classical.

Comment: Take the second order correlation function $g^2(0)=\dfrac{\langle a^\dagger a^\dagger a a \rangle}{\langle a^\dagger a \rangle ^2}$ in the standard Hanbury Brown Twiss experiment. Now, $g^2(0)<1$ surely gives you quantum states of light, but does $g^2(0)>1$ *forbid* you from using the quantum picture? I don't think so. It is just that classical methods work there, and you can choose not to talk about quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks guys. Truth is, now I am even more confused because you're basically confirming what I'm thinking. Correct me if I'm wrong, so there's no one "common"/"universal" operator/indicator for non-classicality. Essentially, any measure that "breaks" what is known classically is eligible to be such a candidate, but it doesn't mean that it'll work for every state that might be quantum...

Comment: @FlyGuy that’s basically correct.  There is no universal witness for this, although the behaviour of singularity of the P-function is as close as you get.

Comment: Absence of a hallmark of QM interference logically cannot imply classicality. How could it? It's just falsification of a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no contradiction because positivity of the Wigner is not enough to guarantee classicality: squeezed states are precisely examples of this.  What is known for pure states (Hudson’s theorem) is that only  Gaussian states have non-negative WFs (at least in the $xp$ plane), but the theorem is silent on the classicality of the Gaussian states.

Most non-classical states have singular [$P$-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonclassical_light), although it is recognized that the criteria is not so simple and there are recent results in

> Damanet, F., Kübler, J., Martin, J. and Braun, D., 2018. Nonclassical states of light with a smooth P function. Physical Review A, 97(2), p.023832

that suggest a way of engineering non-classical states so that their P-function behaves more smoothly.

I do not know of a necessary and sufficient condition for a state to be classical, although negativity in the Wigner function guarantees it is NOT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ZeroTheHero. This is still kind of baffling me. So what criteria do people use to say that squeezed states are actual quantum states?

Comment: The link to the wiki page provided above will partially answer your question: squeezed states cannot be described in classical E&M.  This isn’t a very satisfactory answer but I’m afraid that if you are looking for a mathematical criterion there just isn’t one yet.

Comment: to add to this: there are no known easily computable necessary and sufficient criteria for nonclassicality. There are, however, hierarchies/classes of criteria which are necessary and sufficient, in the sense that one is ensured that if a state is nonclassical, then one of the criteria wlil witness such nonclassicality (but of course, one can never know using only a finite number of these criteria that the state is classical; you can only gather increasing amounts of evidence towards that hypothesis). See e.g. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.89.283601

Comment: @glS ah yes.  I was looking for that reference but could not remember the authors or the details.  Thanks for linking to this.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I would also add that Hudson theorem, as far as I'm aware, is only valid for *pure* states. For pure states, non-negativity of the Wigner is equivalent to the Gaussianity of the state. I don't think the equivalence holds more generally

Comment: Thank you guys for the help!